# rxjs subscription issue while updating the component UI

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable, subscription

I am currently working on understanding the rxjs Observable, Observer and Subscription.
To understand the same I wrote a sample code for updating UI with the random numbers with the interval of 1 second. My goal is to work on updating the multiple components from a single observable. But I stuck at the point where a component variable is not updating with the subscription's next observer. My code is as below,

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-z11va4?file=src/app/app.component.ts

when I enable `this.updateNumber(num)` it says method is not available. I believe issue is with `this` key word. How to reference class variable and methods from `next()`?

```
this.number1 = 0;

clickSix() {
        this.number1 = 1;
    
        const randomGeneratorOnIntervalObservable = new Observable(
          this.obsCheckService.randomGeneratorOnIntervalSubscription
        );
    
        randomGeneratorOnIntervalObservable.subscribe({
          next(num) {
            console.log(num);
            // this.updateNumber(num);
            this.number1 = num;
          },
          complete() {
            console.log('Finished sequence');
          },
        });
        this.number1 = 2;
      }
    
      updateNumber(num: number) {
        this.number1 = num;
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use arrow function to solve this problem:

```
randomGeneratorOnIntervalObservable.subscribe(
    (num) => {
        console.log(num);
        this.updateNumber(num);
        this.number1 = num;
    },
    (error) => {
        console.log(error);
    },
    (complete) => {
        console.log('Finished sequence');
    });
  this.number1 = 2;
}
```

Update:

```
randomGeneratorOnIntervalObservable.subscribe({
     next: (num: number) => {
        console.log(num);
        this.updateNumber(num);
        this.number1 = num;
    },
     error: (error: Error) => {
        console.log(error);
    },
    complete: () => {
        console.log('Finished sequence');
    }});
  this.number1 = 2;
}
```

Note: Unlike regular functions, arrow functions do not have their own **this**. The value of **this** inside an arrow function remains the same throughout the lifecycle of the function and is always bound to the value of this in the closest non-arrow parent function.

Reference Documentation
https://betterprogramming.pub/difference-between-regular-functions-and-arrow-functions-f65639aba256

Comment: it resolved the issue but I couldn't understand, what is the difference between these two. Also, this subscribe method is deprecated too.

Comment: I added an explanation about this
I hope it is useful

Comment: Thanks. Understood the concept. Also, added one reference for the others.

Comment: Your welcome and thanks you for add reference Documentation